# Flutter: how to launch and android intent and return data to flutter

Tags: android, dart, kotlin, flutter

Like the title says, im looking to launch an android intent from flutter but then after doing an operation, for it to return the result back to flutter.

Comment: May sounds weird. But you shouldn't use "Hi", "Hello", or whatever similar. Nor "thanks". https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: If intent is to an external app, then platform specific code as per Darky's answer. If you mean startActivityForResult, then check out https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#what-is-the-equivalent-of-startactivityforresult

Answer (score 2):

What you want is most likely to use platform-specific code.

You can look here for more info on own to write native android code in flutter. https://flutter.io/platform-channels/